# Error on adding UINavigationbar button with image

Tags: swift, xcode, hamburger-menu

I'm trying to add an UIBarbutton with image on my UINavigationbar. However, the button moves to the center instead of keep on the left, also the image becomes huge. Can you guys help me, please?

[image: Hamburguer Icon]

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Delegate TableView
        self.tableViewTopSell.delegate = self
        //SetupNavBarCustom
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.CustomNavigationBar()
        let logo = UIImage(named: "tag.png")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
        self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
        //Hamburg Menu
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(UIImage (named: "hamburgIcon"), for: .normal)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 35.0, height: 35.0)
        //button.addTarget(target, action: nil, for: .touchUpInside)
        let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [barButtonItem]
```

Comment: You set nil to navigation bar's leftBarButtonItem.  You then set an array of items to the same.  Isn't that redudant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Custom Left-bar button image :**

```
    let btnBack = UIButton()
    btnBack.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "back"), for: .normal)
    btnBack.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    btnBack.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    btnBack.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let leftBack = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: btnBack)

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBack
```

> Also check the size of image which you are trying to set for left-bar
>   button.
>   I used 35 x 35 for 2x image and 53 x 53 size for 3x image.